# Multiple instances of Redux WP Framework

Tags: theme-options

Is it possible to have multiple instances of Redux WP framework? Not subpages, i need multiple separate instances since 10+ subpages with tons of options is really really slow.

Comment: This is probably best asked at its developers/support. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lead dev of Redux here. You sure can! Just be sure to specify a different opt_name as well as a different page_slug and you're golden. Redux was built to do just that.